# The active space of transition state of ch3oo+nh3

Tags: multi-reference

I am trying to calculate the potential energy surface of the reaction:ch3oo+nh3=ch3ooh+nh2, because of the high T1 diagnostic value, the multireference method needs to be used in Molpro. I gave the active space apace step by step, and everything seemed good until active space was (7e,6o), one active orbital refers to an o-o π orbital shows in reactant active orbital can not be included in transition states active orbital. Whatever how I rotate the orbital, it does not work, I have been struggling with this for months, so I attached an input file and ask for your advice and recommendation.
Thank you all very much!

````
(5e,5o):
memory,2000,m
geomtyp=xyz        ! use cartesian coordinates xmol style
geometry={
10              ! Number of atoms
CNH6O2
  C         1.572679000000      0.578668000000      0.205525000000
  H         2.316893000000      0.970482000000     -0.487615000000
  H         0.957089000000      1.394772000000      0.599585000000
  H         2.059437000000      0.052969000000      1.029229000000
  O         0.782634000000     -0.313673000000     -0.552640000000
  O        -0.136935000000     -0.901245000000      0.303994000000
  H        -1.121895000000     -0.504387000000     -0.043836000000
  N        -2.093944000000      0.366523000000     -0.112760000000
  H        -1.677239000000      1.262678000000     -0.376582000000
  H        -2.478346000000      0.505153000000      0.824559000000
}


set,spin = 1

basis=aug-cc-pvtz


   {multi;
   closed,15;
   occ,20;
   wf,35,1,1;
   rotate,15.1,16.1,0;
  ! open   define open shell orbitals 
   orbprint,10;
   }
   put, molden,ch3o2h_nh2_ts1_5e5o.molden
   RS2C,SHIFT=0.25


ENCBS= energy

(7e,6o):
memory,2000,m
geomtyp=xyz        ! use cartesian coordinates xmol style
geometry={
10              ! Number of atoms
CNH6O2
  C         1.572679000000      0.578668000000      0.205525000000
  H         2.316893000000      0.970482000000     -0.487615000000
  H         0.957089000000      1.394772000000      0.599585000000
  H         2.059437000000      0.052969000000      1.029229000000
  O         0.782634000000     -0.313673000000     -0.552640000000
  O        -0.136935000000     -0.901245000000      0.303994000000
  H        -1.121895000000     -0.504387000000     -0.043836000000
  N        -2.093944000000      0.366523000000     -0.112760000000
  H        -1.677239000000      1.262678000000     -0.376582000000
  H        -2.478346000000      0.505153000000      0.824559000000
}


set,spin = 1

!basis=aug-cc-pvtz
basis=cc-pvdz


   
   
   {multi;
   closed,14;
   occ,20;
   wf,35,1,1;
   rotate,14.1,15.1;
  ! open   define open shell orbitals 
   orbprint,10;
   }
   put, molden,ch3o2h_nh2_ts1_7e6o.molden
   !RS2C,SHIFT=0.2


ENCBS= energy
```
````

Comment: Hi, I made some changes to formatting to make the input file block look nicer. Also, i would recommend migrating this to matter modelling stack exchange - that forum is more targeted towards this type of questions.

Comment: "ch3oo+nh3=ch3ooh+nh2" seems like an ignorant and careless attempt to write a chemical equation.